# Meme Generator: Canvas is not defined

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a meme generator with Javascript.

This meme generator basically gets three inputs from the user and adds the text into the image.

This is my [script.js](https://www.paste.org/125366) file.

Now it works fine and perfectly and adds the text into the image.

But I also need to make those added texts draggable so the user can drag them around with his mouse.

Now in order to do that, I changed the script to [this one](https://www.paste.org/125367).

But this one does not load the image and shows the message **`Uncaught TypeError: canvas is undefined`** at Console.

So if you know what's going wrong here, please let me know...

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys.

This is also the html part:

```
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <div id="canvasWrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <div>
    <h3><i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Source Image</h3>
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <p>From URL</p>
        <input id="imgURL" class="block" type="text" placeholder="Link to image" />
        <a href="http://memeful.com/" target="_blank">Memeful.com</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>From Local Disk</p>
        <input id="imgFile" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
        <label for="imgFile" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i></label>
      </div>
    </div>


    
    <h3><i class="fa fa-commenting-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Meme Text</h3>
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <p>Top Text</p>
        <input id="textTop" type="text" class="block" placeholder="Top text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Bottom Text</p>
        <input id="textBottom" type="text" class="block" placeholder="Bottom text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <p>Middle Text</p>
        <input id="textMiddle" type="text" class="block" placeholder="Middle text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Middle Text Size: <span id="textSizeMiddleOut">10</span></p>
        <input id="textSizeMiddle" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="10" class="slider" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <h3><i class="fa fa-text-height fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Text Size</h3>
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <p>Top Text: <span id="textSizeTopOut">10</span></p>
        <input id="textSizeTop" type="range" min="2" max="50" step="2" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Bottom Text: <span id="textSizeBottomOut">10</span></p>
        <input id="textSizeBottom" type="range" min="2" max="50" step="2" />
      </div>
    </div>

    
    
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <h3><i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Preview Size</h3>
        <input id="trueSize" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="trueSize"><span>Show true size</span></label>
      </div>
      
      
      
      <div>
        <h3><i class="fa fa-download fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Export</h3>
        <p>If the button doesn't work, right-click the image and save it</p>
        <p>If you are one mobile, download the source image and directly upload it</p>
        <button id="export">Export!</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear:
`Uncaught TypeError: canvas is undefined`

That means you are using a variable (canvas) before it was defined.
Looking at the code you have `var x = canvas.width / 2;` at the top,
but that canvas variable is initialized way after, you have a comment there:
`// Initialize canvas and context`

A simple fix is to moved the initialization to the top, that will take care of the error.

---

I also increased the text size to 28 to get a better view and added shadowColor, shadowBlur that way the text has better contrast ove white background

before:
[image]

after shadow:
[image]

see code below, the error is gone.

```js
// Initialize canvas and context
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var canvasWrapper = document.getElementById('canvasWrapper');
canvasWrapper.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.shadowColor="black";
ctx.shadowBlur=7;

var isDragging = false;
var dragOffsetX = 0;
var dragOffsetY = 0;
var textParts = [];
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = textSizeTop + padding;
var lh = 1;
var textSize = 28;
var textSizeTop = 28;
 
// CANVAS.js plugin
(function (window, document) {
  /**
   * CANVAS Plugin - Adding line breaks to canvas
   * @arg {string} [str=Hello World] - text to be drawn
   * @arg {number} [x=0]             - top left x coordinate of the text
   * @arg {number} [y=textSize]      - top left y coordinate of the text
   * @arg {number} [w=canvasWidth]   - maximum width of drawn text
   * @arg {number} [lh=1]            - line height
   * @arg {number} [method=fill]     - text drawing method, if 'none', text will not be rendered
   */
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawBreakingText = function (
    str,
    x,
    y,
    w,
    lh,
    method
  ) {
    // local variables and defaults
    var textSize = parseInt(this.font.replace(/\D/gi, ''));
    var textParts = [];
    var textPartsNo = 0;
    var words = [];
    var currLine = '';
    var testLine = '';
    str = str || '';
    x = x || 0;
    y = y || 0;
    w = w || this.canvas.width;
    lh = lh || 1;
    method = method || 'fill';
 
    // manual linebreaks
    textParts = str.split('\n');
    textPartsNo = textParts.length;
 
    // split the words of the parts
    for (var i = 0; i < textParts.length; i++) {
      words[i] = textParts[i].split(' ');
    }
 
    // now that we have extracted the words
    // we reset the textParts
    textParts = [];
 
    // calculate recommended line breaks
    // split between the words
    for (var i = 0; i < textPartsNo; i++) {
      // clear the testline for the next manually broken line
      currLine = '';
 
      for (var j = 0; j < words[i].length; j++) {
        testLine = currLine + words[i][j] + ' ';
 
        // check if the testLine is of good width
        if (this.measureText(testLine).width > w && j > 0) {
          textParts.push(currLine);
          currLine = words[i][j] + ' ';
        } else {
          currLine = testLine;
        }
      }
      // replace is to remove trailing whitespace
      textParts.push(currLine);
    }
 
    // render the text on the canvas
    for (var i = 0; i < textParts.length; i++) {
      if (method === 'fill') {
        this.fillText(
          textParts[i].replace(/((\s*\S+)*)\s*/, '$1'),
          x,
          y + textSize * lh * i
        );
      } else if (method === 'stroke') {
        this.strokeText(
          textParts[i].replace(/((\s*\S+)*)\s*/, '$1'),
          x,
          y + textSize * lh * i
        );
      }
    }
  };
})(window, document);
 

 
// Add event listeners
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseUp);
 
// Set initial values
var padding = 15;
var textTop = 'i don\'t always make a meme';
var textMiddle = 'but when i do, I use ninivert\'s generator';
var textBottom = 'but when i do, I use ninivert\'s generator';
var textSizeMiddle = 28;
var textSizeBottom = 28;
var image = document.createElement('img');
 
// Load image
image.src = 'https://imgflip.com/s/meme/The-Most-Interesting-Man-In-The-World.jpg';
image.onload = function () {
  drawMeme();
};
 
// Draw meme on canvas
function drawMeme() {
  // Clear canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 
  // Draw image
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 
  // Set text styles
  ctx.font = textSizeTop + 'px Impact';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
 
  // Draw top text
  ctx.drawBreakingText(
    textTop,
    canvas.width / 2,
    textSizeTop + padding,
    canvas.width - 2 * padding,
    lh,
    'fill'
  );
 
  // Set middle text styles
  ctx.font = textSizeMiddle + 'px Impact';
 
  // Draw middle text
  ctx.drawBreakingText(
    textMiddle,
    canvas.width / 2,
    canvas.height / 2,
    canvas.width - 2 * padding,
    lh,
    'fill'
  );
 
  // Set bottom text styles
  ctx.font = textSizeBottom + 'px Impact';
 
  // Draw bottom text
  ctx.drawBreakingText(
    textBottom,
    canvas.width / 2,
    canvas.height - padding,
    canvas.width - 2 * padding,
    lh,
    'fill'
  );
}
 
// Handle mouse down event
function onMouseDown(e) {
  var mouseX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var mouseY = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
 
  if (
    mouseX > 0 &&
    mouseX < canvas.width &&
    mouseY > 0 &&
    mouseY < canvas.height
  ) {
    isDragging = true;
    dragOffsetX = mouseX - x;
    dragOffsetY = mouseY - y;
  }
}
 
// Handle mouse up event
function onMouseUp() {
  isDragging = false;
}
 
// Handle mouse move event
function onMouseMove(e) {
  if (isDragging) {
    x = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left - dragOffsetX;
    y = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top - dragOffsetY;
    drawMeme();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <div id="canvasWrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <div>
    <h3><i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Source Image</h3>
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <p>From URL</p>
        <input id="imgURL" class="block" type="text" placeholder="Link to image" />
        <a href="http://memeful.com/" target="_blank">Memeful.com</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>From Local Disk</p>
        <input id="imgFile" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
        <label for="imgFile" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i></label>
      </div>
    </div>


    
    <h3><i class="fa fa-commenting-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Meme Text</h3>
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <p>Top Text</p>
        <input id="textTop" type="text" class="block" placeholder="Top text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Bottom Text</p>
        <input id="textBottom" type="text" class="block" placeholder="Bottom text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <p>Middle Text</p>
        <input id="textMiddle" type="text" class="block" placeholder="Middle text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Middle Text Size: <span id="textSizeMiddleOut">10</span></p>
        <input id="textSizeMiddle" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="10" class="slider" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <h3><i class="fa fa-text-height fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Text Size</h3>
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <p>Top Text: <span id="textSizeTopOut">10</span></p>
        <input id="textSizeTop" type="range" min="2" max="50" step="2" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Bottom Text: <span id="textSizeBottomOut">10</span></p>
        <input id="textSizeBottom" type="range" min="2" max="50" step="2" />
      </div>
    </div>

    
    
    <div class="box">
      <div>
        <h3><i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Preview Size</h3>
        <input id="trueSize" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="trueSize"><span>Show true size</span></label>
      </div>
      
      
      
      <div>
        <h3><i class="fa fa-download fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Export</h3>
        <p>If the button doesn't work, right-click the image and save it</p>
        <p>If you are one mobile, download the source image and directly upload it</p>
        <button id="export">Export!</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

... and I noticed that in your HTML you have a lot of inputs to control the final result, but none of them have any JS code yet, you still have a LOT of work to get these controls to work and make those added texts draggable.

Comment: Are you sure the snippet work correctly?

Comment: @firer the snippet fixed the `Uncaught TypeError: canvas is undefined`, that was the error  in the question, if we click on the Run code snippet button the image loads and the text is on top of the image ... as of "working correctly" you have to be a bit more specific, I mentioned in the last paragraph that there are many inputs that have no code behind

Comment: The inputs work correctly with the first script that I provided (https://www.paste.org/125366) but now with your edition of course they don't work!

Comment: @Pouya look at the code on the second script (that is the one that has the error and that is the one I fixed) there is no JS code there for the inputs,

Comment: @Pouya looking closely at the two scripts the first one has 248 lines of code your second one only 207. You removed a lot of things! ... but the error you reported in the question (`canvas is undefined`) is now fixed if you follow my solution ... the rest is up to you.